# Questions about the rendering behavior of multiple render target on Unity. Or Shader's problem?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

I tried to get a general render image, depth image and Id (pre-assigned for each material) image using multiple render target in Unity.

First, look at this image.

[image]

`RenderTexture` output by multiple rendering targets is assigned in the three vertically stacked boxes. From below, the rendered image, depth image, and Id image are assigned.

I expected the depth and id images to be colored only where the box is.
However, I ran into an issue where the color of the previous frame remained.
I thought it was a problem around z buffer, but I couldn't solve it.

this is sample [repository on github.](https://github.com/nenoNaninu/MRTSandbox)

shader code

```
Shader "Custom/MRT"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Id ("Id", float) = 0.5
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 100

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                float depth : TEXCOORD1;
            };

            struct buffer {
                float4 buf1 : SV_Target0;
                float4 buf2 : SV_Target1;
                float4 buf3 : SV_Target2;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;
            float _Id;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                COMPUTE_EYEDEPTH(o.depth.x);
                o.depth *= _ProjectionParams.w;
                //for debug visualizing
                o.depth *= -1;
                o.depth += 1;
                //end debug
                return o;
            }

            buffer frag (v2f i)
            {
                buffer o;
                // sample the texture
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);

                o.buf1 = col;
                o.buf2 = float4(i.depth.x, 0, 0, 1);
                o.buf3 = float4(0, _Id, 0, 1);

                return o;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

C# code

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

public class MRTCamera : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject Template;
    public Material StandardMaterial;
    public Shader MrtShader;

    private Camera _camera;
    private RenderTexture[] _renderTextureArray;
    private RenderBuffer[] _colorBuffers;
    private RenderTexture _depthBuffer;

    void Start()
    {
        _camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
        _camera.enabled = false;

        _renderTextureArray = new RenderTexture[3]
        {
            new RenderTexture(640,480, 0, RenderTextureFormat.Default),
            new RenderTexture(640,480, 0, RenderTextureFormat.Default),
            new RenderTexture(640,480, 0, RenderTextureFormat.Default),
        };

        _renderTextureArray[0].Create();
        _renderTextureArray[1].Create();
        _renderTextureArray[2].Create();

        _colorBuffers = new RenderBuffer[]{ _renderTextureArray[0].colorBuffer, _renderTextureArray[1].colorBuffer, _renderTextureArray[2].colorBuffer };

        _depthBuffer = new RenderTexture(640, 480, 24, RenderTextureFormat.Depth);
        _depthBuffer.Create();


        var o1 = Instantiate(Template, new Vector3(0, 2, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        o1.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = new Material(StandardMaterial) { mainTexture = _renderTextureArray[0] };

        var o2 = Instantiate(Template, new Vector3(0, 3, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        o2.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = new Material(StandardMaterial) { mainTexture = _renderTextureArray[1] };

        var o3 = Instantiate(Template, new Vector3(0, 4, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        o3.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = new Material(StandardMaterial) { mainTexture = _renderTextureArray[2] };
    }

    void Update()
    {
        _camera.SetTargetBuffers(this._colorBuffers, this._depthBuffer.depthBuffer);
        _camera.RenderWithShader(MrtShader, "");
    }
    void OnDestroy()
    {
        _renderTextureArray[0].Release();
        _renderTextureArray[1].Release();
        _renderTextureArray[2].Release();

        _depthBuffer.Release();
    }
}
```

Comment: You camera seems to have `DONT CLEAR` set as Clear flags so the zBuffer is never cleared

Comment: Thank you for your quick comment!
The camera's Clear Flag was set to Skybox, but when I changed it to Solid Color, it behaved as intended.